# Building Multi Level Menu Dynamically with PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hierarchy

I have this data in my database:

```
id  nameOfPerson    parent
3   John             NULL
4   Michel            3
5   Husam             4
6   Khalaf            5
7   Mark              5
----------------------------
```

and i want to display it in list like this

- John

  - Michel

    - Husam

      - Khalaf
      - Mark

but in my code he just displayed

- John

  - Michel

How i want to Displeyed all data according to parent like above list ?

this is my function whats the wrongs ?

```
  public function familyTree(){
    $query = "SELECT id, nameOfPerson, parent FROM person WHERE parent is null";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute();
    echo '<ul id ="family">';
    while($family = $statment->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo '<li>'. $family->nameOfPerson;
        $query1 = "SELECT id, nameOfPerson, parent FROM person WHERE parent = :id";
        $statment1 = $this->db->prepare($query1);
       $statment1->bindValue('id', $family->id);
        $statment1->execute();
        if($statment1->rowCount() > 0){
        echo '<ul>';
        while($family2 = $statment1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            echo '<li>' . $family2->nameOfPerson . '</li>';
        }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
            echo '</li>';
    }
            echo '</ul>';      

}
```

Comment: I would encurage you to first get _all_ the data out of database and write it in a well structured array. _Then_ build the html of that with a recursive function.

Comment: Thanx for your advice, i will learning what you encourage me. 
I 'am fresh self learning, my question is did there solution to solve this problem with out change the code now ?

Comment: you defenitely need a recursive function (a function that calls itself for all the children)

Comment: @Jeff i make the parent foreign key from the id ... that's a good step or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASSUMPTIONS**

- Every child has only `1` parent.

**CODE**

- First, I retrieve all data from DB table as it is not efficient to retrieve data individually for each parent increasing DB calls and affecting response time.
- Build an associative array of parent and children where every parent has 2 details of `each child` - `nameOfPerson` and `id`.
- Iterate over this array in a recursive way and keep building the list for each child and ultimately return them.

Refer [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43019e/1) for table rows.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=newdummy;host=localhost","root","");

$query = $pdo->query("Select * from hierarchy");

$family_tree = [];
$root_parent = -1;
$root_parent_name = "";

function makeTree($query,&$family_tree,&$root_parent,&$root_parent_name){
   while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      if(is_null($row['parent'])){
          $root_parent = $row['id'];
          $root_parent_name = $row['nameOfPerson'];
      }else{
          if(!isset($family_tree[$row['parent']])){
            $family_tree[$row['parent']] = [];
          }          
          $family_tree[$row['parent']][] = array($row['nameOfPerson'],$row['id']);
      }    
   }
}

function buildList($family_tree,$parent){
  $list = "<ul>";

  foreach($family_tree[$parent] as $each_child){
     $list .= "<li>" . $each_child[0];
     if(isset($family_tree[$each_child[1]])){
        $list .= buildList($family_tree,$each_child[1]);
     }
     $list .= "</li>";
  }

  $list .= "</ul>";

  return $list;
}


makeTree($query,$family_tree,$root_parent,$root_parent_name);


echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>$root_parent_name";
echo buildList($family_tree,$root_parent);
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<ul>
    <li>John
        <ul>
            <li>Michel
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Husam
                            <ul>
                                <li>khalaf</li>
                                <li>Mark</li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Tross</li>
            <li>David</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```